# How can a Windows file have invalid hidden characters

Tags: visual-studio, filenames

The application I work on has file upload capability. We recently found that a user was able to upload a couple of files that have filenames with an invisible invalid character. In the VS debugger this appeared as a question mark, and in SQL Server, where the filename was stored, it appeared as a pipe symbol. Any ideas on how a non-technical user could have accidentally saved a file with such a filename?

Comment: Probably a copy-paste job. These unusual characters have a way of appearing various places on the Internet. I don't know why you've reached the conclusion that the character is "invalid", though. It's more likely that it's a Unicode character you don't have the proper glyph to display. If it were actually *invalid*, as in not supported by the underlying file system, you should have gotten an error. The obvious solution is to sanitize input, including file names. But no reason to be overzealous about this, as it seems everything *worked fine* here.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause (I have experieced it myself):

### The filesystem on the other machine has different encoding.

This is with Windows since existence of that dialog box:

[image: Region control panel.]

As you can see, there is still a code page and it can be changed. It is not mentioned there, but **it applies also to the file system.** After the change, some characters used in file names can change or become illegal. You can test that on your machine. Create a file `ľščťžýáíé.txt` (copy-paste the name for purpose of testing), then change file system encoding (you can use the two visible above, the problem was reproducible with them when I tried some time ago) and check the file name. I also confirm that file names containing certain such characters cannot be even *open* after such a change until you revert the encoding back to the original one.

**So do not assume the user uploads the file with the same filesystem code page as your server (or application) uses. It is a wrong assumption.**

MSDN [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748(v=vs.85).aspx):

> NTFS stores file names in Unicode. In contrast, the older FAT12, FAT16, and FAT32 file systems use the OEM character set. For more information, see Code Pages.

So some of problems can originate at file system encoding. Some from how you are handling national characters in your processing chain. **Did you test your system on preserving all Unicode characters on their way from upload to download?**

By the way, are you using UTF-8 code page in your database?

And are you quoting UTF-8 strings correctly in literals? I.e. using `N'štring'` instead of `'štring'` whenever the string contains a character outside 7-bit ASCII range i.e. where `AscW(c) >= 128`. The era of A-Z, a-z is over, even U.S. developers have to correctly handle internationalization.

Answer (score -2):

I think they just typed the pipe char " | " in the filename like:
example|filename.txt

Since pipe is a delimiter, this would be seen as a possible hack.

I have used code in many languages VB, SQL, C# that parse the filenames before working with them.